# gitlab-runner's git clone fails with "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"

Tags: ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

For several months now I've had issues with `gitlab-runner` which is randomly failing with the following log:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.7.0 (943fc252)
  on <gitlab-runner-name> <gitlab-runner-id>
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on <hostname>...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /var/gitlab-runner/builds/<gitlab-runner-id>/0/<gtlab-group>/<gitlab-project>/.git/
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@<hostname>/<gtlab-group>/<gitlab-project>.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

This line is the crucial one:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@<hostname>/<gtlab-group>/<gitlab-project>.git/': Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

I tried unregistering the runner and registering a new one. It also failed with the same error after a while (the first run usually worked well).
Furthermore, runners on other machines are working correctly and never fail with the error message above.

I believe the issue is caused by the missing `CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE` file in:

```
/var/gitlab-runner/builds/<gitlab-runner-id>/0/<gtlab-group>/<gitlab-project>.tmp/CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
```

I tried doing a `git pull` in the faulty directory and I got the same message. After I copied this missing file from another directory which had it, I got the following:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab-ci-token:<gitlab-runner-token>@gitlab.lab.sk.alcatel-lucent.com/<gtlab-group>/<gitlab-project>.git/'
```

As far as I know, these tokens are generated for a one-time use and are discarded after the job finishes. This leads me to believe the missing file is the issue.

Where is this file copied from? Why is it missing? What can I do to fix this issue?
I've been looking through the GitLab issues without luck.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I've disabled the SSL verification by adding `environment = ["GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true"]` into `[[runners]]` section of the gitlab-runner toml config. I haven't seen the error in the two weeks since I've added it.

Comment: Or just run `git config http.sslVerify false`, same effect without having to dig into the linux directories. Thanks for your comment though, it led me to find it :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one or more of your runners doesn't trust the certificate on your gitlab host. You'll have to track down the root and intermediate certs used to sign your TLS cert, and add it to your runners' hosts.

For my runners on CentOS, I follow this guide (for CentOS, the commands are the same for higher versions): https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html.

Comment: `git clone` works correctly when I try it outside the gitlab-runner environment. E.g. I log into gitlab-runner user and run `git clone <myrepo-url>`. It gives me access denied but that's fine because gitlab CI/CD is managing its own access tokens. I even tried `openssl s_client -connect myhost:443` and it connected correctly.

Comment: Sometimes you have to add the cert in a custom Docker image if using the Docker executor, but I see you're using shell. In my experience it should be the same as running it on the command line, so I'm not sure what the issue might be. I'll start a bounty though to draw more attention to the issue.